# Swift how to create an effect similar to it of UIPageViewController between a UIViewController and UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on a project involving scrolling between a UIViewController and a UITableViewController. I tried to use a UIPageViewController to hold a UIViewController and a UITableViewController, but the .setViewControllers function kept giving me an error.

Can someone give me a sample code for creating something similar in effect to a UIPageViewController between a UIViewController and UITableViewController?

Comment: What error it is giving? Can you please post your code and error ?

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to use a UIPageViewController to hold a UIViewController and a UITableViewController, but the .setViewControllers function kept giving me an error

Nevertheless, a UIPageViewController is an excellent way to do this. You should concentrate your efforts on that.

Alternatively, as you have only two view controllers in play, you could make your own custom parent view controller with the UIViewController and UITableViewController as children, and display their views in a UIScrollView yourself.

As a final alternative, don't use a scrolling interface: use a UITabBarController instead, with the two view controllers as its children. This is easy to configure (you can do it directly in the storyboard). It is possible to make a UITabBarController horizontally scrollable, and I have explained elsewhere how to do it, but the topic is rather advanced.